# hHover an element when DIV is scrolled into view

Tags: javascript

As the title says , i want a suggestion on how to hover an element when the div i want is scrolled into view. 
I already tried something like :

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
  $(window).scroll(function(){

    if (isScrolledIntoView('.class') === true) {
        $('.class').addClass('in-view')
    }
    else { $('.class').removeClass('in-view'); }
```

But it doesn't fit quite right for my needs , so i'm asking for a better solution if it's one. I want something like the menu on the right:

developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial . Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean something like a jQuery UI dialog? https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: By hover do you mean "focus"?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial i want something like the menu on the right.

Comment: Look for "sticky menu" or "sticky navigation" on the internet.

Comment: What you are asking for is a sticky menu/navigation. What do you mean it doesn't fit your needs? In what way?

Comment: Yea sorry for the miss leading question but i didn't know how to ask it . If i'm using the script i posted i need to write alot of if's , so i'm looking for something easier.

Comment: We have no idea of what you are asking if you don't write it in your question :). Please [edit] your question to include all information necessary to provide an answer. See [ask] for more information about what we're looking for in a question.